# lock inside a simple property - can it deadlock?

Tags: c#, locking, deadlock

**Questions:**

1. Can I deadlock this code? Does the IsMouseInside property is thread safe?
2. Does the use of the copy variable make sense?

PS: UI thread updates IsMouseInside. Another thread will read its value some times

```
    public Class Test    
    {

    private readonly object isMouseInsideLocker = new object();
    private bool isMouseInside = false;

    public bool IsMouseInside
    {
        get
        {
            bool copy;
            lock (this.isMouseInsideLocker)
                copy = this.isMouseInside;
            return copy;
        }
        set
        {
            lock (this.isMouseInsideLocker)
                this.isMouseInside = value;
        }
    }

    private void lblProcessTime_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsMouseInside = true;
    }

    private void lblProcessTime_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsMouseInside = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: To determine "thread safe", we need to know what the context is in terms of how it is being used.

Comment: PS: UI thread updates IsMouseInside. Another thread will read its value some times

Comment: without some kind of memory barrier, the answer you have accepted may not be guaranteed to work (it may be cached); it is really complex to determine either way, though. Personally I would use *something* here -not justna naked field accessor.

Comment: but isnt a lock a memory barrier? Can you explain more?

Comment: yes it is; my meaning there was: it was unclear in the accepted answer whether it is still using the `lock` - it needs *something*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, you can't.
2. It doesn't. Just `return isMouseInside;`

Answer (score 2):

No that can't deadlock; there is only one lock object, and no extension point exists that would allow you to do something messy while the lock is held. However, if you are using lock you should probably make it clear what scenarios you are trying to avoid.  While the meaning is actually very subtle, I wonder whether `volatile` might work here without needing any locks. Or `Interlocked` on an `int` that is always either `0` or `1`.

But sure, it looks like it'll work; bool is always atomic anyway, so the lock here is only really acting as a memory-barrier avoiding cache issues (hence why volatile might also work). And remember that any time you get the value, that is now stale and might already be incorrect. It was true at the point of read, though.

Comment: Ive stoped using volatile since I read this: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx.

Comment: @Pedro yes, volatile is complex and subtle - but *in this case* it would serve the same purpose

Comment: I just want to know at moment of the read, no problem if it changes just after becouse I will check it again when I need. I will take your advise and I will read more about volatiles.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't deadlock - you are locking on the same object.
2. It doesn't make sense to me. Also the locking doesn't make sense - I don't think you achieve anything with it.

What is the goal?

Comment: UI thread updates IsMouseInside. Another thread will read its value some times, that is why Im using the lock.

Comment: All right, but you are locking for a single operation. You don't need to do that.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain? locking a bool is only usefull for memory barrier since it is an atomic variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can only have a deadlock if you have two different locks A and B that two different threads try to acquire in different order - since you only have one lock here you are safe.

Also keep in mind that C# lock (which is syntactic sugar for using a [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx)) is [reentrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex) - a single thread cannot deadlock since it can reenter a lock as many times as it wants to once it has initially acquired it.

Comment: I think I can deadlock with something like  X += X, and X is a int and uses the kind of lock that I did.

Comment: @Pedro: That still would work since `lock` is reentrant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex

Comment: @Pedro how would X+=X be a deadlock? at worst it could be data loss due to conflicts (Interlocked.Add would be preferred), but that is different to a deadlock.

Comment: @BrokenGlass in that scenario re-entrancy is unrelated; that is 2 "get"s and a "set" - *but each separately*. Unless of course you explicitly lock for the duration, but then the locks in the accessors seem unnecessary.